# How to change specific element of a nested List?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, put

I have two models, Ignicoes and Ocorrencias. Ignicoes has a list of Ocorrencias as an attribute. Here are there classes:

Ignicoes class:

```
   public class Ignicoes
{
    public enum EstadoIgnicao
    {
        aceite,
        emAvaliacao,
        concluido,
        recusado
    }

    public Ignicoes()
    {
        ListaOcorrencias = new HashSet<Ocorrencias>();

    }

    
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    //estado(recusada, aceite, em avaliacao, concluido)
  
    [Required]
    public EstadoIgnicao Estado { get; set; }

  
    public DateTime DataInicioPropostaIgnicao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataDecisaoIgnicao { get; set; }


    //lista de ocorrencias 
    public virtual ICollection<Ocorrencias> ListaOcorrencias { get; set; }

}
```

Ocorrencias class:

```
public class Ocorrencias
{

    public enum EstadoOcorrencia
    {
        aceite,
        emAvaliacao,
        recusado
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// código que identifica de forma única o aparelho que comunica a ocorrência
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Dispositivo { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// data da ocorrencia
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public DateTime DataOcorrencia { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// coordenadas GPS - Latitude
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// coordenadas GPS - Logitude
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Azimute do ?angulo formado entre o Polo Norte e o fogo
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Azimute { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Foto a provar a ocorrência
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Fotografia { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Nome a atribuir à fotografia guardada no disco rígido
    /// </summary>
    public string NomeFotografia { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// estado da ocorrencia : aceite, em avaliação, recusado
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public EstadoOcorrencia Estado { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Ignicao")]
    [Display(Name = "Ignicao")]
    public int? IgnicaoFK { get; set; }
    public virtual Ignicoes Ignicao { get; set; }



}
```

In my PUT method of my ignicoes controller I want to update the property "Estado" of each Ocorrencia in listaOcorrencias.Meaning I need to access the property Estado in the variable listaOcorrencias. How should I do that?
Here is my PUT method:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PutIgnicoes([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Ignicoes ignicao)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }


        if (id != ignicao.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        else
        {
            var dataDecisao = DateTime.Now;
            var ig = _context.Ignicoes.FirstOrDefault(ignicaoId => ignicaoId.Id.Equals(id));
            if (ig != null)
            {
                ig.Estado = ignicao.Estado;
                ig.Latitude = ignicao.Latitude;
                ig.Longitude = ignicao.Longitude;
                ig.DataDecisaoIgnicao = dataDecisao;

          // I need to access the property Estado in the variable listaOcorrencias

                
                
            }
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!IgnicoesExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it seems that you want to update the related entities. Since the related entities has already existed in the database, first, we could according to the existing property to find them and modify the value, then, update the database.

Code as below:

```
           if (ig != null)
            {
                ig.Estado = ignicao.Estado;
                ig.Latitude = ignicao.Latitude;
                ig.Longitude = ignicao.Longitude;
                ig.DataDecisaoIgnicao = dataDecisao;

                // I need to access the property Estado in the variable listaOcorrencias
                //create a new list to store the updated items.
                List<Ocorrencias> newlist = new List<Ocorrencias>();
                // loop through the Ocrrencias
                foreach(var item in ignicao.ListaOcorrencias)
                {
                    //based on the properties to find the special Ocrrencias
                    var existitem = context.Ocorrencias.Where(c => c.IgnicaoFK == id && c.Dispositivo == item.Dispositivo).FirstOrDefault();

                    // if the item not existed, you can create a new Ocorrencias, and add to the list. Then, it will add a new record in the Ocorrencias table.
                    //modify the value.
                    existitem.Estado = item.Estado;
                    //add the item to the list.
                    newlist.Add(existitem);
                }
                //assign to the Ignicoe.
                ig.ListaOcorrencias = newlist;

                //update 
                context.Ignicoes.Update(ig);
            }
            try
            {
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            { 
            }
```